# Counting letter in a group of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Create a list with every class member's first name. Then build a loop that prints out the classmate's name from the list and counts the number of letters in each name. At the end of the loop, print the name of the class mate with the longest name.
For example, if the list of names in  your class is Dave, Tom, Ivan, Margaret, and Maria, the output should be.

```
Dave 4
Tom 3
Ivan 4
Margaret 8
Maria 5
Longest Name is Margaret
```

How would i do this. I need help. Thanks

Here is my current code:

```
from collections import Counter 
names = ["Ryan", "Ian", "Pat", "Dom", "Louis", "Ryan", "Marisa", "Owen", "Matt", "Fines", "Jack", "Gare", "Annie", "Brett", "Cole"] 
print(names) 
for letter in names: 
    print(names.count(letter))
```

Comment: Don't ask us to do your homework. Tell us what you tried and what failed, maybe in this way we could help you.

Comment: "How do I do [entire homework assignment]" is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Show us the code you have written and describe how it does or does not meet your expectations.

Comment: from collections import Counter
names = ["Ryan", "Ian", "Pat", "Dom", "Louis", "Ryan", "Marisa", "Owen", "Matt", "Fines", "Jack", "Gare", "Annie", "Brett", "Cole"]
print(names)
for letter in names:
 print(names.count(letter))

Comment: I tried that and it would print the names and it would spit out a bunch on numbers but I do not know what it was counting

Answer (score 2):

len() returns the length of whatever is in the brackets, if it's len(your_list) it will return the number of elements in the list

max(your_list, key=len) the important part here being "key=len", else max(your_list) would return maximum in terms of pythons sorting method, picking a word with a letter closest to the end of the alphabet, z for example. key=len instead makes it return the longest element

```
names = ["Ryan", "Ian", "Pat", "Dom", "Louis", "Ryan", "Marisa", "Owen",
         "Matt", "Fines", "Jack", "Gare", "Annie", "Brett", "Cole"]
for name in names:
    print (name,' ',len(name))
longest = max(names, key=len)
print ('\nLongest name: ',longest,' with ',len(longest),' letters.')
```

prints:

```
Ryan   4
Ian   3
Pat   3
Dom   3
Louis   5
Ryan   4
Marisa   6
Owen   4
Matt   4
Fines   5
Jack   4
Gare   4
Annie   5
Brett   5
Cole   4

Longest name:  Marisa  with  6  letters.
```

Alternatively if you wanted to store the information for later use I suppose you could use a dictionary to do so, and every time you iterate over a name in the list, check it's length against the length of the name in the dictionary.

When looking up values in a dictionary you do it by "keys" usually surrounded in square brackets, if the key is a variable you can do it like so:

```
my_dictionary = {} #create an empty dictionary
variable = ('mystring')
my_dictionary [variable] = 10
print (my_dictionary)
```

prints:

```
{'mystring': 10}
```

but if you don't use a variable to add a dictionary key, and instead use a string you have to write the key like so

```
my_dictionary ['mystring']
```

or using an integer as a key:

```
my_dictionary [1]
```

anyways here is your code:

```
longest = {'name': '', 'length': 0}

for name in names:
    print (name,' ',len(name))
    if len(name) > longest ['length']:
        longest ['name'] = name
        longest ['length'] = len(name)

print ('\nLongest name: ',longest['name'],
       ' with ',longest['length'],' letters.')
```

Comment: You are the best. Thank you

Answer (score -3):

Your Print command is wrong!

```
from collections import Counter
names = ["Ryan", "Ian", "Pat", "Dom", "Louis", "Ryan", "Marisa", "Owen", "Matt", "Fines", "Jack", "Gare", "Annie", "Brett", "Cole"]
print(names)
for letter in names:
    print((letter))
```

Comment: This doesn't count anything.

Comment: OP update his question after i answered...

Comment: Question asked about counting from the beginning.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks, Realized that now :)!